# how to add custom field under shipping address in checkout magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping

how to add custom field under shipping address in checkout   magento 2?

[image: checkout]

Comment: This is too broad question. Answer would be so huge if anyone tried to. please use https://mage2gen.com/ to generate new module, use 'Customer Attribute' option and you can create your own address attribute on checkout

Comment: I have already done customer_attributes in customer_account_create page https://prnt.sc/o6wshs how to show a customer_attributes in checkout page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do refer following steps to add new custom field under shipping address on checkout Page,

> https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-field-checkout-address-form-magento2/